# Transferring Matlab variables to C

Tags: c++, c, matlab, variables

I have a very large data structure in some Matlab code that is in the form of cells of arrays.  We want to develop C code to work on this data, but I need some way to store the Matlab variable (which we generate in Matlab) and open it in a C/C++ program.  What is the easiest way to bridge the two programs so I can transfer the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only moving the data from MATLAB to C occassionally, the easiest thing would be to write it to a binary file, then read from the file in C. This of course leaves the C code completely independent of MATLAB.

This does not have to be that messy if your data structure is just a cell array of regular arrays, e.g.

```
a{1} = zeros(1,5);
a{2} = zeros(1,4);
```

You could just write a header for each cell, followed by the data to the file. In the above case, that would be:

```
[length{1} data{1} length{2} data{2}]
```

In the above case:

```
5 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
```

If the arrays are 2D, you can extend this by writing: row, column, then the data in row-major order for each cell.

This might not be entirely convenient, but it should be simple enough. You could also save it as a .mat file and read that, but I would **not** recommend that. It is much easier to put it in a binary format in MATLAB.

If you need to move the data more frequently than is convenient for a file, there are other options, but all I can think of are tied to MATLAB in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mex files:

http://www.mathworks.fr/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html

Comment: The C code needs to be independent of Matlab.  We are only using Matlab to generate input values.  Even something as simple as printing them to a file and reading them with the C code would be an option, but because they are large cells of matrices, this is an ugly solution and I was wondering if there was a better method.

Answer (score 0):

If the two processes need to connect during their lifecycle,  you have plenty of options:

- Compile Matlab DLL.
- Use Matlab Engine.
- Compile MEX file (as @Oli mentioned earlier)

If the communication is offline (After Matlab closes, C++ starts to read), then you should use filesystem. Try to format it in XML, it is a well recognized standard.